# Multiple ports server for Server/Client program in C

Tags: c, sockets, unix, tcp

I want to make a Server/Client program in C where the server has 2 ports, each one of them doing different things, and I don't know how to handle this. I thought about creating 2 different sockets for each port but no clue what do to after this. Looping infinitely and checking each socket if a client connected to one of them or what is a better approach for this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to make 2 threads, 1 for each port. When you open the socket to start listening and call the `accept()` function, the thread will block until there is a connection, no need to loop.

Answer (score 0):

> don't know how to handle this.

There are two common approaches:

- separate thread to service each port
- [epoll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)

If the actual work on the different ports is completely unrelated and doesn't require coordination, thread-per-port is likely a better model.

Comment: I already use threads for working with clients and I wonder if it would make the things awkward. I checked the epoll and I want to ask if I can create the ev like an array and do that operations for ev[0] and ev[1]. Also if I check for each socket  `if (events[n].data.fd == listen_sock{1,2})` on each else I call the functions responsible for each port, right?

Comment: @BalentinValtatescu Yes, you can. You'll need two separate calls to `epoll_ctl` with `EPOLL_CTL_ADD`, but it doesn't care whether your data is in an array or not.

Comment: Employed Russian I made that I can access both ports but the problem is I can't use them at the same time, the first used port is open and keeps waiting for new clients on its end, I can establish the connection with other port but if I ask for data or anything else no response. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @BalentinValtatescu It's impossible to help you without http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I can't add the specific part. Server: (https://www.codepile.net/pile/yrXpPvrd) and client: (https://www.codepile.net/pile/wBAqM7By) it's something basic before I add the part to my main program  I Tried switching the if/else or just having the manage function in if but nothing changed. I am probably approaching it wrong.

Comment: @BalentinValtatescu In the server code, line 204 appears to have a cut/paste error; surely you meant to pass `&ev` and not `&ev2` ?

Comment: You also appear to call `accept` too many times: once in the `main` loop, and again in `manage`.

Comment: Yeah, it was a copy/paste error but didn't affect cause it's the 2nd port and accepts it correctly. I tried to play with the accepts, but if I only have the `manage` function in `if` from events loop the first port used either of them will dominate and can't send/receive data from the other port. I am truly confused solving this.

Comment: Also tried the nonblocking operation in `manage` function but still same thing.